# How to accept SOH character from TextField in JAVAFx

Tags: java, javafx

I have written  simple GUI screen that actually contains a JavaFx textField where the user enters a string and that String I have to pass to TCP client.

Now the problem is user enters a string that contains SOH as the delimiter.
SOH is nothing but "\u001". But when the user enters a String that contains this delimiters then it is removed and only the simple plain text is retrieved. How can I eliminate this. This unique character is very important for me.
For example my string is as follows:

```
8=FIX.4.2\u001 9=9 \u001 35=A \u001 34=1\u001 49=TTDS68AP
```

Observer the above String where I have the \u001 character representing SOH. But when I entered this String in the TextField then the result is like:

```
8=FIX.4.29=9135=A34=149=TTDS68AP
```

How can I get the SOH character too from the Text Field?

Comment: How are you verifying that it's removed?

Comment: How does the user enter the SOH character?

Comment: Dump `Arrays.toString(s.toCharArray())`.

Comment: @Kayaman  By debugging I can able to see the text that is entered in the textfield. Actually I will be storing the data into a String object that is entered in the TextField. So I can able to place a breakpoint there and can see that no SOH character is there in the String

Comment: @Joop can you please elaborate it more.

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(textField.getText().toCharArray()))` should verify that the character was indeed removed (thanks for @Kayaman's suggestion). Debugging would be feasible too. But just _displaying the string_ is not helpful with a control character.

Comment: @Joop Yes it is removing the character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that javaFX `TextField` filters invalid characters with the following [function](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.java#TextInputControl.isInvalidCharacter%28char%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29):

```
private static boolean isInvalidCharacter(char c, boolean newlineIllegal, boolean tabIllegal) {
    if (c == 0x7F) return true;
    if (c == 0xA) return newlineIllegal;
    if (c == 0x9) return tabIllegal;
    if (c < 0x20) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This happens after you paste and before the String is stored in the field. Before this function is called a custom filter can be set and applied, in this filter you can change `SOH` to something else; it's unicode representation [␁](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2401) is a good candidate:

```
textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>((t) -> {
    t.setText(t.getText().replace((char)1, '\u2401'));
    return t;
}));
```

Adding the above will change it after it's pasted and before it's stored. When you want to use the `String` from the textField you need to replace it back to `SOH` with:

```
String withSOH = field.getText().replace('\u2401', (char)1);
```

Comment: So I am using the above filter in the initialize section of the controller. But the same thing repeats. While displaying it on the console, I couldn't see the SOH character. Basically my String will be like 
 8=FIX.4.2SOH9=91SOH35=ASOH34=1SOH49=TTDS68APSOH
This string when pasted into the TextField I couldn't see in the field and also I couldn't see when getText()  method is used from the field.

Comment: Are you setting it for the correct `TextField`? What do you see? It works for me, I can paste a string with `SOH` and see it. If you can't get it to work please post a [mcve]

Comment: Yes. I have written the code like 
cutomStringTextField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>((t) -> {
            t.setText(t.getText().replace((char) 1, '\u0001'));
            return t;
        }));
in the initialize section. And when the submit button is clicked the action event retrieves text from the field as 
String text = cutomStringTextField.getText().replace('\u0001', (char)1);
        System.err.println(text);

Comment: I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7028e4187912bbe3c4708f9e398b1f64) if you run it, paste `SOH` in the TextField and click on the button it will output `1` to the console.

Comment: Sorry. You have mistook my problem I guess. I will be entering a String that contains SOH character some where in the middle which can be represented as "\001" in JAVA. So when I gave this String in the TextField then the getText() method should give me the exact String including the \001 character in the String. But it is removing it.

Comment: @hemachandra If you add `field.setText("8=FIX.4.2\001 9=9 \001 35=A \001 34=1\001 49=TTDS68AP");` to the gist I posted you will see the character in the app, you will get the exact same String with `field.getText.replace('\u2401', (char)1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160474/discussion-between-hema-chandra-and-oleg).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you want to enter by keyboard and see the control character in the text field:

- Ctrl-A (SOH) is a known shortcut, and selects the previous character.
- The control character will not be displayed in a normal font.

So I came to the following solution:

```
    String SOH_REPR = "°"; // We show SOH as this string.
    someTextField.setOnKeyPressed((ke) -> {
                if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("A")
                        && ke.isControlDown()
                        && !ke.isAltDown()
                        && !ke.isMetaDown()
                        && !ke.isShiftDown()) {
                    TextField textField = (TextField) ke.getSource();
                    ke.consume();
                    int pos = textField.getCaretPosition();
                    textField.insertText(pos, SOH_REPR);
                }
            });
    someTextField.setOnKeyReleased((ke) -> {
                if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("A")
                        && ke.isControlDown()
                        && !ke.isAltDown()
                        && !ke.isMetaDown()
                        && !ke.isShiftDown()) {
                    ke.consume();
                }
            });

// Convert it back.
String text = someTextField.getText().replace(SOH_REPR, "\u0001");
```

Pasting text with SOHs would still needed to be done for completeness sake.

Comment: No sir, I don't want to see it in textField. All I want is, when I store it in a String object the String should not loose the SOH character.

Comment: Then `SOH_REPR = "\u0001"` should suffice

Comment: Sorry sir. It is not working. And moreover I am not typing using keyboard. I am pasting the string directly

Comment: And at the end I already said that pasting still not done. I hope Oleg's answer fits better.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the your encoding as argument.

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "yourEncoding");
```

I think UTF-8 should work.